# Parsing unusual tags in rss feed using php. (Have the tag <dc:author>)

Tags: php, parsing, rss, feed

I have researched this but have had trouble implementing it into my code. I have:

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('FEEDURL');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array ( 
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,

//author
'author' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/','dc') >item(0)->nodeValue

);
array_push($feed, $item);
}
?>
```

the section with the comment `//author` is where I am having problems. The tag in the RSS Feed is `<dc:author>`

If you have a relevant article that I have missed, please send me there and don't vote down. Thanks :)

Comment: I know it's not the question, but if you want to be able to read almost any RSS/Atom feed, you should have a look at the [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dc` is namespace, `author` is a tag name, so if `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/` is namespaceURI for `dc` you need to search like this:

`$node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/','author')`

Comment: ohhh! I see now! Thanks so much for your response! It's really appreciated! :)